# Can I bring Whey Protein powder through US customs

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

Can I bring Whey Protein powder through US customs when entering the US? Also what is the process like bringing and declaring food at customs, will it slow down entry a lot?

Comment: whey protein is widely available in the united states, and you should have no problem buying some while here

Comment: Yeah, I understand. It would have been a matter of convenience. Not having to throw the one I have now out and not having to buy it while I'm there.

Answer (score 2):

The answer seems to be No:

["Animal Products:
Meat, milk, egg, poultry, and their products, including products made with these materials are either prohibited or restricted from entering the United States. For further information, please visit the Don’t Pack A Pest website."](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-3619?language=en_US#:%7E:text=You%20must%20declare%20all%20food,can%27t%20enter%20the%20country.)